# Can $u''-4u'=8$ with initial conditions be solved using matrices?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm solving $$u''-4u'=8\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
subject to  the initial contitions $u(0)=-4$ and $u'(0)=-6$ from [lem.ma](https://www.lem.ma/content/AaopF9CNsTmoipRy71x6SA?book_id=BpCFAP27bgq6U3D-ympsug).

I can solve this by finding the homogeneous solution, $u_h$, and the particular solution, $u_p$; then add them by the superposition principle and use the boundary conditions to calculate the arbitrary constants, or I can use Laplace Transforms and Partial Fractions; both give me the correct answer: $$u(t)=-2t-3-e^{4t}$$
However, this question appeared in the context of a linear algebra course and the answer was given in the form: $$u(t)=-2t-1-e^{4t}-2$$

While this is equivalent I wonder what method gives the answer grouped in that way and whether it uses matrices?

---

Here is how I solved it:

The reduced equation is: $u''-4u'=0$
Its corresponding equation is $r(r-4)=0$, so $r=0$ and $r=4$ which leads me to
$$u_h=c_1+c_2e^{4t}$$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants.

For the particular solution I use the mesthod of undetermined coefficients:
Try $u_p=At^3+Bt^2+Ct$ and substitute it in \eqref{eq1}.
This gives me $$u_p=-2t$$

Adding them up I get my general solution: $$u(t)=-2t+c_1+c_2e^{4t}$$
Finally I substitute the boundary conditions and find that $c_1=-3$ and $c_2=-1$ giving me the solution $$u(t)=-2t-3-e^{4t}$$

Comment: You mean $u_p=at$ for the particular solution ?

Comment: You mean for the trial solution? There I let $u_p=At^3+Bt^2+Ct$ because it's a second order equation, so the polynomial would be of order two, but the differential equation is missing a term in $u$, so I increase the power of t by one in each term of the trial polynomial.

Comment: You got it wrong... The guess should be $u_p=At$  Try it.

Comment: Ah yes, I see! I confused the order of the differential equation with the order of the input. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome Kael.

Comment: I would assume that the method used was described somewhere in the course materal leading up to this exercise. No doubt one would first convert this into a linear first-order system by defining $v=u'$.

Comment: That said, $1$ and $e^{4t}+1$ are linearly-independent solutions of the homogeneous equation, so I can certainly see how you might end up with a linear combination of them, but neither method that I tried produces this particular pair of solutions—I get either $\{1,e^{4t}\}$ or $\{1,e^{4t}-1\}$. You’ll have to go back to the course material to reverse-engineer the given solution completely.